# How to initialize git in main directory and subdirectories?

Tags: git, github, terminal

I have a main directory with a client and server. React initialized git in the client, and I initialized git in the server to deploy to heroku.

I then initialized git in the main directory so I can have 1 repo for both client/server instead of 2 separate ones. But when I push it github, it only shows the folders client and server, and none of the actual files inside of them. According to this warning in terminal it's because I have initialized git in multiple folders. How do I fix this so git sees all folders and files?

[vscode terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOuzO.png)

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> clientt
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached clientt
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.`enter code here`
```

Comment: Initializing a Git repository in one directory includes all subdirectories. By creating additional repositories in the subdirectories you've probably made everything very confusing and complicated.

Comment: do you know i could fix this?

Comment: Delete the `.git` directories in the subdirectories again.